# if :checked add class to this

Tags: jquery

I have a small problem. I want to check if a checkbox is checked and if it is checked, I want to add a class to his first brother.
HTML :

```
    <input class="box" type="checkbox">
    <p class="red">Red text </p>

    <input class="box" checked type="checkbox">
    <p class="red">I want this text in blue </p>
```

JS :

```
    if(jQuery(".box").is(":checked")) {
    jQuery(this).next().attr('class', 'blue');                              
}
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/LVEqn/

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add the class 'blue' to all elements following a checked box, do this :

```
$(".box:checked").next().addClass('blue');
```

If you want to replace the existing class, do

```
$(".box:checked").next().attr('class', 'blue');
```

If you want this to be dynamic, that is change when the user checks or unchecks, do

```
$(".box").change(function(){
    $(this).next().attr('class', $(this).is(':checked') ? 'blue' : 'red');
});
```

[DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/uuChJ/)

Comment: Thanks, all works fine. I don't know why I didn't found this earlier :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
jQuery(".box:checked").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).next().attr('class', 'blue');
})
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LVEqn/2/  ​

Answer (score 1):

jQuery

```
$(".box:checked").next().addClass("blue");
```

CSS

```
.blue {color: blue !important;}
```